# Installing Flash Builder 4.7 Plugin on Eclipse failing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adobe, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

I am trying to install Flash Builder 4.7 Plugin into Eclipse.  I have downloaded Flash Builder Premium via Adobe's Creative Cloud.  I have also installed Eclipse Indigo (recommended via Adobe).  I am running this all on Mac OSX.

According to a tutorial I found I needed to go into the Utilities folder found in the Flash Builder install and run the **Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Plug-in Utility**.  It seemed to run fine.  Afterwards you should be able to see "Flash Builder" in the help menu of Eclipse.  However it is not there.  You should also be able to set Flash Builder preferences under Window --> Preferences.  Flash Builder is also not visible there.

I looked into the installation log and there was only one concerning message.

```
Move File:  Destination: /Applications/eclipse/dropins/fb-4_7-plugin-encoded.link
Status:  WARNING
Additional Notes:  WARNING - There was a problem moving /Applications/eclipse/dropins/fb-4_7-plugin-encoded.link
```

I am unsure what this means and Adobe documentation is pretty sparse.  However, it seems to be the only problem in the entire installation process.  Any ideas or suggestions on what could be causing this error would be great.

EDIT:  According the the tutorial there should also be this file "fb-4_7-plugin-encoded.link" created in the "dropins" folder of Eclipse.  This file *is* created.  However it is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are notes I made trying the plug-in with Eclipse, both Indigo and Juno.

Flash Builder 4.7 works Eclipse Indigo or Juno, either 32-bit or 64-bit.  You must use the correct source Flash Builder 4.7 when installing the plug-in – the 32-bit plug-in does not work with 64-bit Eclipse and vice-versa.

One major difference between Flash Builder 4.6 and 4.7 is the removal of Design mode for Flex .mxml files.

To install the plug-in, go to the Flash Builder 4.7 installation directory (usually C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 for the 32-bit version or C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 for the 64-bit version).  Run the Plug-in Utility in the utilities directory.  The installer will prompt for an Eclipse installation directory.

Alternately, create the file dropins/fb-4_7-plugin-encoded.link with the following contents:

```
path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7
```

or

```
path=C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 bit)
```

Adjust the path to the Flash Builder install directory.

Running the Plug-In Utility also creates an uninstall program to remove the plug-in from Eclipse.  This is not created when using the link file to install the plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Eclipse 4.2.2 (Juno) 64-bit version running on Windows 8 Pro and successfully added ColdFusion Builder 3 (64-bit) to Eclipse (since adding ColdFusion Builder to Flash Builder Standalone no longer works).  The Flash Builder plug-in Utility installs correctly and even provides the link file in drop-ins directory of Eclipse correctly.  Yet, if it doesn't show any of the Flash Builder content in Eclipse, you will need to uninstall Flash Builder entirely from your computer and then reinstall.  Then run the plug-in utility from the utilities directory and it should work.

So the steps would be:

1. Make sure any version of Flash Builder is completely uninstalled from the computer first!
2. Install Eclipse and make sure it is the same bit version as the Flash Builder and/or Coldfusion Builder (either 32-bit or 64-bit)
3. Install ColdFusion Builder and select as plug-in to existing Eclipse
4. Install Flash Builder
5. Run Plug-in Utility from Adobe Flash Builder install directory
6. Open Eclipse and set workspace.  You can then add both ColdFusion and Flash perspectives